# Unity now rolled its own dependency injection framework. What's the future of Inject?

Tags: unity-game-engine, dependency-injection, zenject, entity-component-system

With Unity's Entity Component System data-driven design, it has introduced its own DI framework, including even [Inject] field attributes.

https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/EntityComponentSystemSamples/blob/master/Documentation/content/ecs_in_detail.md#injection

How will Zenject integrate into its new coding paradigm?

Comment: You should probably ask Zenject.

Comment: You can use both as suggested here:  https://forum.unity.com/threads/request-for-world-addmanager.539271/#post-3558224